# How to embed PDF files in HTML to access both static and dynamic PDF files

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, pdf

I want to view Pdf files(both static and dynamic files)in IE.I am using the below code to view pdf files but its showing alert 'access denied'.

```
<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="E:/ITEM_HED/IETM_SHared/IETM_SharedPackage/IETM_CheckedinFiles/Model/C3/subu05238520140930120914.pdf" type="application/pdf">
```

I have also tried Object tags but same thing is happening.Is there any other solution to embed pdf files.

Any help/suggestions will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use your direct directory location. **E:/ITEM_HED/IETM_SHared/**.. Instead give a path on your server where your web is published.. like http://localhost/webappx/pdfs/subu05238520140930120914.pdf , which exists in the folder $webappx_project_dir/pdfs